# Hard constraints are not solving in Optaplanner task assignment

Tags: constraints, drools, optaplanner, planning

I am using the Optaplanner Task Assignment solver to assign 68 tasks of 37 customers to 5 employees. Hard constraints are as follows -

1. Tasks have to be completed in 6 days.
2. Only one task of a Customer can be completed in one day.
3. A task has to be started and completed on the same day.
4. All tasks of a customer has to be assigned to the same employee.

The total combined time of tasks is 240 hours but we have 300 hours available to solve the problem.
If one hard constraint is run at a time it's working also if the first hard constraint is removed tasks are assigned in 10 days.
The problem arises if all four hard constraints are applied at the same time, Optaplanner is not able to solve 10 to 20 hard constraints even after running the solver for hours.

Questions -

1. Can someone please suggest what is wrong with the above problem?
2. By default shift timing of employees is 8 AM to 6 PM, can this be changed? if yes then where it is configured.
3. Can some time gap of 1-2 hours be left in the middle of tasks in employee's timings?